# Using astropy fit_wcs_from_points to give FITS file a new WCS

Tags: python, numpy, anaconda, astropy

I used pixel_to_world to find the ra and dec of five stars, and know their xy values in another image. So I feel like wcs_from_points is the correct method by which I should get a WCS on my image.

I have the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.wcs.utils import fit_wcs_from_points
from astropy.coordinates import SkyCoord

stars = np.array([[1246.63, 1372.83, 1455.12, 1611.95, 1644.85],
               [1588.42, 1502.92, 1677.24, 1610.39, 1325.12]])

known_coords = SkyCoord([(125.66419083, -42.96809252), (125.67730695, -42.98209958),
                         (125.65082259, -42.9914015), (125.6611325, -43.01438513), (125.70471982, -43.01228167)],
                        frame="icrs", unit="deg")

fit_wcs_from_points(xy = stars, world_coords = known_coords, projection='TAN')
```

I get this output:

```
WCS Keywords

Number of WCS axes: 2
CTYPE : 'RA---TAN'  'DEC--TAN'  
CRVAL : 125.67776105611648  -42.99124198597975  
CRPIX : 1451.3389930261899  1501.555748491856  
CD1_1 CD1_2  : 6.547003719386885e-07  -0.00011159088984525699  
CD2_1 CD2_2  : -0.00012238492146305314  -1.1457490550730293e-05  
NAXIS : 1645  1678
```

My known image (which is rotated 180 degrees from this image) has the following data, so at least the CRVALs seem correct (I'm still rather new to this so I'm unsure of what approximate these keywords should be populated with):

```
CTYPE1  = 'RA---TAN'           / Pixel coordinate system                        
CTYPE2  = 'DEC--TAN'           / Pixel coordinate system                        
CRPIX1  =    -6457.18566867618 / Ref. pixel of center of rotation               
CRPIX2  =    -4673.96071610528 / Ref. pixel of center of rotation               
CRVAL1  =     125.116590442276 / [deg] [deg] 08:24:31.5 Value of ref pixel      
CRVAL2  =    -43.3619270216124 / [deg] [deg] -42:34:50.2 Value of ref pixel     
CD1_1   =  5.92477204932042E-5 / WCS transform matrix element                   
CD2_1   =  3.73014240770773E-8 / WCS transform matrix element                   
CD1_2   =  -3.4695999305039E-8 / WCS transform matrix element                   
CD2_2   =  5.92440992599392E-5 / WCS transform matrix element
```

I then updated my header of the image:

```
hdulist = fits.open('Swirl06p_1.fits')
header = hdulist[0].header

header.keys
header.set('CTYPE1', 'RA---TAN')
header.set('CTYPE2', 'DEC--TAN')
header.set('CRVAL1', 125.67776105611648)
header.set('CRVAL2', -42.99124198597975)
header.set('CRPIX1', 1451.3389930261899)
header.set('CRPIX2', 1501.555748491856)
header.set('CD1_1', 6.547003719386885e-07)
header.set('CD1_2', -0.00011159088984525699)
header.set('CD2_1', -0.00012238492146305314)
header.set('CD2_2', -1.1457490550730293e-05)
header.set('NAXIS1', 1645, after=3)
header.set('NAXIS2', 1678, after=4)

hdulist.writeto('Swirl06p_1WCS.fits')
hdulist.close()
```

However, the resulting image's WCS is incorrect. it has RA's around 180 and dec's around -3, as opposed to the correct 126 and -43. Also, the NAXISn values differ than what I stored them as, but this makes sense as it is storing it as the length of the axes...

I'm using Anaconda 4.10.3, and my astropy version is 4.3.1, my numpy version is 1.20.3, I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS, if that helps.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

Got it to work in one cell, thanks to help. This is my final code (in case anyone else experiences this later, haha)

```
hdulist = fits.open('Swirl06p_1.fits')
header = hdulist[0].header
stars = np.array([[1246.63, 1372.83, 1455.12, 1611.95, 1644.85],
               [1588.42, 1502.92, 1677.24, 1610.39, 1325.12]])

known_coords = SkyCoord([(125.66419083, -42.96809252), (125.67730695, -42.98209958),
                         (125.65082259, -42.9914015), (125.6611325, -43.01438513), (125.70471982, -43.01228167)],
                        frame="icrs", unit="deg")

w = fit_wcs_from_points(xy = stars, world_coords = known_coords, projection='TAN')
hdulist[0].header.update(w.to_header())
hdulist.writeto('Swirl06p_1WCS.fits')
hdulist.close()
```

Comment: To update the header with the WCS, please use hdulist[0].header.update(wcs.to_header()). Can you also check if there are duplicate  WCS parameters present?

Comment: that worked, thank you!

Comment: After obtaining wcs values by fit_wcs_from_points, can we run pixel_to_world(x, y)  directly without changing the header of fits or even loading fits ?